# My PC mic does not work

Tags: drivers, sound, microphone

I have a Dell laptop but I am unable to call my buddy due to no sound transfer from my PC to the friend. How to solve this problem? I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking top right of the screen and going to settings > sound. Then open the "input" tab. Sometimes the mic volume is on zero there.

Comment: I did this i can hear the callers voice but my voice does not transferred to the caller

Comment: O thank you I  get it and its working properly.

Comment: I'm glad its working :)  Please mark the answer as solved.